# Which generic collection should i choose in C# to maintain sorted "list"

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, generic-collections

I have Node class which has a float Distance property.

I want a data structure that i can put inside it all my nodes and they will be stored sorted (like in AVL tree or Red Black Tree).

- I want to insert in O(log(n))
- I want to retrieve and remove the minimum in O(log(n))

I tried to use sorted dictionary but it proved completely useless because he can't hold  two items that have the same distance.

Using list and Sort i out of the question because removal is (O(n)) and finding Minimum is also (O(n))

All i need is a simple generic red black tree structure that will sort by some predicate i'll provide (which is to compare the Distance inside Node)

Is there such data structure in the BCL ?

Comment: Oh, I don't know.. how about `SortedList<>`?  I know the name is vague and confusing ;)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx  SortedDictionary can be used as a list, and it has O(log n) insertion and removal.

Comment: Did you try the SortedList Class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx

Comment: What you want is a heap, and I don't think the BCL has one built in, so you'll have to write your own or find some existing implementation.

Comment: @MystereMan - Removal from a `SortedList` is O(n).

Comment: @Lee - I know, I updated my comment to point out that a sorted dictionary has O(log n) insertion and removal, and you can then use that as a list.

Comment: @JimMischel - Perhaps you should read the entire comment

Comment: sorted list is O(n) on removal. which is problematic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the c5 Collections Library's `TreeBag<T>` class. It's a red-black tree that allows duplicates (hence, *bag* rather than *set*). access by index of item value is O(log n); insertion and deletion are O(log n) amortized.

The C5 Collection Library was funded by Microsoft; it's open-source and available *gratis*. The price is right.

http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can use `SortedDictionary` for this. But what you need (assuming the distance is `int`) is a `SortedDictionary<int, List<Item>>`.

When you want to add a distance that's not in the dictionary yet, you insert a new `List` containing a single item. When you want to add a distance that is already in the dictionary, find the right list and add the item to it.

To remove the smallest item, find the `List` with the smallest key and remove an item from it. If the `List` becomes empty, remove it from the dictionary.

Since removing from the start of a `List` is inefficient, you will either need to remove from the end of the `List` (resulting in LIFO order for items with the same key), or use a `Queue` instead of `List`.

This is probably not the most efficient solution, but insertion, finding smallest item and removing smallest item are all O(log n).

Comment: +1 Complete explanation. Side note: I suspect that your optimizations of remove-from-list part are not applicable as most likely items with same key must be compared with `Equals` to find correct one instead of just removing arbitrary one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The question asks for removing the smallest item, not a specific item.

Comment: I see it now - somehow I read it as "remove item" instead of "remove an item with minimum key" - deleted my answer as unrelated because of it.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). The .NET Framework doesn't have one, but I implemented one in C# a while back. See [A More Memory-Efficient Skip List](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=876).

The skip list has O(log n) insertion, search, and removal, and O(1) removal of the top item.

If you want a heap, see [A Generic Binary Heap Class](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789).